# How to use search and replace for all the columns in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I need to have a search and replace function that would search through all the columns in a table and would replace all the comma<,>, double quote<">, and single quotes<'> with space. I have gone through the blogs like  http://vyaskn.tripod.com/sql_server_search_and_replace.htm. But the methods there do not work.

Comment: What does not work? The solution you pointed looks promising. What have you tried? What problems are you facing?

Comment: I need it to work on only one table rather then all the tables in the whole database. Also the above stated stored procedure does not work for integers, decimal, numeric datatypes.   
                                              To have it only for one table I used this :-                        Declare      @TableName  nvarchar(50)='t_recur'                                                        And to use it only for columns in the table  I have removed the part where it sets the table name for all tables in the database Plz advice

Comment: You expect a replace to work on int / decimal / numeric? I'm afraid you're out of luck. If you see commas and such in those columns it's because of how they're presented, not because of how they're stored.

Answer (score 3):

```
DECLARE @table NVARCHAR(257) = N'dbo.table_name';

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'UPDATE ' + @table + ' SET ';

SELECT @sql = @sql + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) 
    + QUOTENAME(name) + ' = '
    + ' REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(' 
    + QUOTENAME(name)
    + ','','', '''')'
    + ',''"'', '''')'
    + ',''' + CHAR(39) + CHAR(39) + ''', ''''),'
FROM sys.columns
WHERE system_type_id IN (167, 175, 231, 239)
AND [object_id] = OBJECT_ID(@table);

SET @sql = LEFT(@sql, LEN(@sql)-1) + ';';

PRINT @sql;
--EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

Comment: Corrected the check against sys.types to just use system_type_id constants instead. Since it's possible you could game it by using `CREATE TYPE not_a_char FROM int;`...

Comment: Hi Aaron,Thanks for the solution. But when I executed it it gave me the following error:-  Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near 'SE'. Can you please advice some solution for this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you get that error message when you print, or only when you execute? Did you print to try to debug the output? Grasping but do you have tables or column names with spaces?

Comment: I got this error when I executed it. But I used a stored procedure to remove all the unwanted characters(double quotes, commas and single quotes) thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 2):

To take out the commas:

```
update mytable
  set myColumn = REPLACE(myColumn, ",", " ")
```

For the double quote:

```
update mytable
  set myColumn = REPLACE(myColumn, "''", " ")
```

For the single quote:

```
update mytable
  set myColumn = REPLACE(myColumn, "'", " ")
```

For more information see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx

Comment: OP need a solution that will replace for all columns in a table.

Comment: Hi Chris,Thanks for your response but as Adrian mentioned I need one command to execute on all columns using sys.columns r something similar.